# Rearrange an image into random tiles?

Tags: images, tiles

I want to rearrange an image so that it becomes 4 tiles, but not one of the tiles is in its original place. Which software does that automatically? I don't need the separate tiles files, I just want the original image to be rearranged automatically and have the option to save it like that. Thank you!

Comment: Get also a look at [Fred's Shuffle Script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/shuffle/index.php) for [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org).